# Post variables from a while loop from a second table in form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql

I'm trying to grab a two variables from 2 columns (cover and pageno). As you can see the select is for the name column so I can't grab the other variables and insert them into the cover and pageno columns.  I have values in the inputs but there's one issue.

1. If there's more than one book it will echo all covers and all pageno for all books in the input values.
2. When the db is populated it does the same as the value, it populates the columns with all - covers and pageno's for all books instead of the specific book selected.

I'm not sure how to loop through the inputs and print only the book selected and populate the db with what was selected only. Maybe javascript of Jquery? I hope that makes sense.

```
<select name="name">
<option value="<?php echo "{$_POST['name']}"; ?>"> </option>                      

<?php
include('theconnection.php');
$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$dbName);
if (!$con)
{
die('cannot connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
mysqli_select_db($con,"thebooks");

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT b.id, b.name, b.cover, b.pageno FROM books");

$cover = '';
$pageno = '';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo ("<option value='$row[name]'>$row[name] $row[cover], $row[pageno] </option>"); 

$cover .= "$row[cover]";
$pageno .= "$row[pageno]";

}

?>

</select>

<input type="hidden" name="cover" value="<?php echo $cover; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="pageno" value="<?php echo $pageno; ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not clear on your question. from what i could make out of it is that the hidden fields cover and page no should only show the selected row. looking at your code i don't get why are you using the select query twice anyway you are not using the first query and can be safely removed and also you can add the where clause to filter out your result and even if that has multiple results you can put some sort of comparison in the while loop but i suggest you do that in the query itself. if showing just one value in the hidden cover and pageno is your motive then you can use

```
$cover = "$row[cover]";
$pageno = "$row[pageno]";
```

if you could explain it more clearly i would be happy to help

Comment: Hi Baljinder,  Thanks for commenting.  Yes you're right the first query doesn't need to be there.  I was testing different things and forgot to remove it.  I'm using the second query.  What I'm trying to do is even if I use the code you posted both books values -  As you can see I have 2 books in the select -  page no 123 is one book and 345 is another book and the cover value is paperhard - paper is one book and hard is the second book.  I only want results for the book selected - one book.

Comment: It's saying below I selected both books which isn't true.  I select one... in other words, it's combining both books in the hidden field values.  
<input type="hidden" value="123345" name="pageno">
<input type="hidden" value="paperhard" name="cover">

Comment: where is the selected book value coming, is it the $_POST['name'] you have in the select. if that is the case you need to add that value to the query like  `$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT b.id, b.name, b.cover, b.pageno FROM books where b.name='" + $_POST['name']+"' ");`  and as for the values being combined  remove the dot(.) before = look at my answer above adding a dot(.) actually concatenates the values.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I added your code and removed the dots which took care of combining both values for pageno and cover which is great.  But the issue now, looking at the hidden values after refresh, it populates the hidden values with the last book when I haven't selected a book.  For a test, I added name id and when a book is selected and I submit it uses the id selected  < (hence validation stops it from submitting and populating db) which is great.  But when I fill out the form and select the 1st book it  populates the db columns with the last book values when I selected the 1st book.

Comment: can you please post the complete code along with the html form and php insert script. i'm still not able to fully understand the issue. the cover and pageno variables will get populated from the last row returned by the sql. so it the query returns 5 rows the 5th row will be the value of cover and page no